# Parse error help, PHP unexpected T_STRING (probably something simple)

Tags: php, mysql

It's probably something simple I am not seeing because I've stared at it too long.

Any ideas?  It's throwing on line 119, I've indicated it below

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home6/cleanai4/public_html/act.php on line 119

I'm just trying to format a phone number.

```
        if(isset($submit)):
        $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "#######", "#######");
        mysql_select_db("###########", $db);
        $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
        $address = $street . ", " . $city . " " . $zip;
Line 19->   $phonetmp = '('substr($phone, 0, 3)')' . substr($phone, 3, 3) . '-' . substr($phone, 6);
        $phone = $tmp;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ########
        VALUES(NULL,'$name', '$address', '$email',  '$phone', '$info', '$sign', '$date' )";
        mysql_query($sql);
        print("<h2>We appreciate your support</h2>\n");
        print("<b>Now, spread the word</b><hr>\n");
    endif;
```

Comment: If code review, then all the way. You should prefer using ' instead of " where possible. You should probably use a better way to approach your DB, may be a ready made class/ORM system/ some kind of abstraction layer etc.

Comment: and some nicer/better way to handle SQL/DB errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the concatenation after the first part of $phonetmp, should be `'(' . substr($phone, 0 , 3) . ')'`...

Also note: unless you have a variable called $tmp outside of the code segment, you're setting $phone to an undeclared variable. And make sure you sanitize user inputs!

Answer (score 2):

That's not a password I'm seeing in the `mysql_connect` call is it? ;)

Comment: oops, thanks for the heads up, hah :)